# bar graphs with nested groupings for repeated measures

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, bar-chart

For a bar graph of repeated measures on different devices I need to plot something similar to this minimal example: 4 tests on 3 different devices, with settings 'high' and 'low' (missing tests are 0):

```r
df = data.frame(test     = c(rep('test 1', 6), rep('test 2', 6),
                             rep('test 3', 6), rep('test 4', 6)),
                settings = c(rep(c('high', 'low'), 12)),
                device   = c(rep(c(rep("device 1", 2),
                                   rep("device 2", 2),
                                   rep("device 3", 2)), 4)),
                values   = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3,
                             3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             4, 3, 5, 3, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 4, 1, 6, 4)
     )
```

I have managed to plot this:

```r
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes (x = device, y = values, fill = settings)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(.~test)

p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 60 , hjust = 1), 
          strip.text.x = element_text (angle = 90))
```

[image: ggplot output 1]

but I would like to

- have different colours for the different devices (so grouping by settings and device)
- have the bars of the 'high' and 'low' measurements next to each other, not stacked

Would that be possible with ggplot?

I also have tried this

```r
q <- ggplot(data = df, aes (x = device, y = values, group = device, 
            fill = test, alpha = settings)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  color = "black") + 
  facet_grid(~test)
```

[image: ggplot output 2]

which almost does the job, definitely for the colours, but:

- the bars are still on top of each other, not side by side / half overlapping
- the lighter colour is at the bottom, which is the other way round from previous examples?

Comment: Try `position = "dodge"` in the `geom_bar()`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet 100% sure about your expected outcome, but it seems that the following is what you aim to accomplish.

```
q = ggplot ( data = df, aes ( x = device, 
                              y = values, 
                            group = settings, 
                            fill = device, 
                           alpha = settings)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_grid(~test)
```

with outcome

[image]

Comment: Yes! "dodge" is the answer, thanks. I'm still looking if I can make the transparent less transparent (say 50%) and swap the colouring of 'high' and 'low' but that should be doable.